# Identification of church in Magdeburg

Tags: germany

I have a photo of a church in Magdeburg where my grandparents were married.  I'm trying to identify the name of the church and determine if it's still standing. They were married in 1919. They were Lutheran.  I've searched for church images but have had no luck identifying it.

Can you help?

[image: Magdeburg church]

Answer (score 6):

I just browsed through several of the churches, and I think it might be Sankt Gertraud ([Wikipedia article](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sankt-Gertraud-Kirche_(Magdeburg))). If you look at some pictures from image search (I used DuckDuckGo and Google), the front and the gate quite well match your photograph (in particular this one: [front view](https://mapio.net/pic/p-91471763/)).

Answer (score 6):

Although jadepx was faster than me, I want to add an answer to this interesting question. I have been in Magdeburg several times and did not recognize this church.

So I turned to [Liste von Sakralbauten in Magdeburg](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_von_Sakralbauten_in_Magdeburg) (Wikipedia). Most churches can be excluded by first sight. Under *Nicht mehr bestehende Kirchengebäude* is a list of churches that don’t exist anymore (most damaged/destroyed during World War II and subsequently completely destroyed during the era of the German Democratic Republic (GDR). Another list of these churches, but with images, can be found on [Kirchensprengung.de](https://kirchensprengung.de/kirchensprengung-magdeburg). None of these churches looks like your church.

Long story short: I agree with jadepx that you are looking for [Sankt-Gertraud-Kirche](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sankt-Gertraud-Kirche_(Magdeburg)), not only from the building itself but also the terrain. Please don’t confuse it with *Sankt Gertraud**en***, another church in Magdeburg.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information, in particular on destroyed churches!

Comment: Thank you both so very much!  My elderly mother was so excited to learn the name of the church and see modern day photos of it.  You made an old lady's day!